# Most efficient way to detect if a series of n edges creates a cycle of size n.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I am working on an algorithm but there is so much about math that I don't know and I could speed up my algorithm a ton if there was a trick here.

I have a weighted, undirected graph.  From this graph I have attained a set of n edges (to, from) where "to" and "from" represent nodes in my graph.

Within this set, every node is represented once and only once as a "to", and once and only once as a "from".

One can probably see that this set will contain at least one cycle.

My question is, what is the fastest way to detect if the set contains *only one* cycle?  That is to say, that the the set of n edges contains a cycle of size n.

I can't come up with anything more efficient than pulling out an edge and then traversing all of it's connections until I have found the length of the first cycle.

Is there something better than this?  Thank you.

Comment: There are very few of us who can claim to have nothing left to learn about maths. I know none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm has worst case runtime linear in $n$, which is already pretty fast. Especially when checking that a sequence of edges is in fact a cycle necessarily takes length-of-cycle-many operations, I wouldn't expect any faster without preprocessing.